# Real-Time validation for a Time Field in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, validation, time

I need to employ a real-time time validation in a PHP form.  Basically, when a visitor is filling out the form (it's a order form btw), and comes to the "pickup time" field, the visitor should only be allowed to enter a time that's one hour (60 minutes) from the time they are filling out the form.  If they fail to enter the appropriate time, it should echo an error.

I don't need real time validation, I need real-time, **time** validation. I mean: filling out a form field, and have the code check the current time the user is putting in (eg. 2:00pm) and respond accordingly. If the time is 2:00pm while filling out the field, an error should occur because the time is not at least 60 minutes from the current time (2:00pm).

How to do this? PHP or otherwise, I only know HTML and CSS.

Comment: To reduce server load, I'd suggest having a Javascript based verification method. Then when everything is ready (as per checked by javascript) the form submit on the PHP side would then re-check everything to verify that the information (or the JS check) has not been tampered with. Javascript has great events such as `onchange` which would allow you to then do checks on the information being passed to, say for example, an `<input>`.

Comment: That sir is called jquery or javascript, i personally prefer to handle it with jquery, and you will add an event handler that will watch for either some change in the content, or some mouse even tht will trigger the validation.